# flask cannot open folder

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use the flask to open a local folder on the browser, like directly typing file:///D:/ to the address bar. but it failed. when I directly run the home.html on the browser it can work successfully. Is there anything wrong? How can I tell Flask works correctly?

Thanks

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])

@app.route('/helloworld')
def helloworld():
    return 'Hello, world!', 200


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

home.html

```
<a href="F:/">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: what is your goal in opening the folder? is it for uploads?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    import os
    arr = os.listdir("F:/")
    return render_template('home.html', arr=arr)
```

and then on template(home.html) list your files accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot, but is there any method to let the page could be operated,  like directly typing file:///D:/ to the address bar?

Comment: You can pass the value as parameter in another url and can fetch other lists also.